# ACLs on macOS: ACE "deny delete" on macOS with APFS broken? File not writable in GUI

Tags: macos, unix, permissions, filesystems, acl

Since the UF_NOUNLINK Unix flag is actively being thwarted by macOS, I was thinking about using a self-made shell script to achieve a similar functionality with an ACL, namely to prevent accidental deletion of a file or directory, while retaining full permissions & access otherwise, read, write, execute, change attributes, change XAs, change owner/group/permissions etc. The command I'm using for the ACE is the following:

`chmod -h +a# 0 "group:$access_group deny delete" "$filepath"`

I have created a special group (`$access_group`) with `dscl` which I only want to use for this kind of access control, and I've added my user (501) to that group.

Now, the basic functionality works: unlike the `uunlnk` Unix flag, the `deny delete` ACE blocks me from moving or renaming the file—why? because an ACL is not tied to the inode?—, but the good thing is that deletion is not possible for my 501 user, because it's part of the special group that's covered by the `deny delete`.

The problem, however, is that the ACL now also prohibits file modifications, e.g. editing the file in TextEdit etc.: macOS tells me that the file is allegedly "locked", which it is not, because I can edit the file just fine on the command line, e.g. with `echo "foo" >> bar`.

Sidenote: I'm getting the same behavior, when I modify the command to

`chmod -h +a#0 "user:$(id -un) deny delete" "$filepath"`

So the fact that I'm using a special group isn't causing the problem. But what could be the reason for this weird behavior? Does it have to do with the way macOS is saving files in the GUI? Or does the ACL have to be created in a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TextEdit, and many other macOS programs, use atomic writes to edit files. That is, they write out the new file contents to a temp file, then rename the temp file over the original file (unlinking it as a side effect). This is done so that if the program crashes while writing the new contents, you aren't left with a broken half-written file.

This does have some weird effects: Editing a file requires delete/unlink permissions to it (and write access to the directory it's in). After editing, the file will have a different inode number (because it's a different file, just with the same name). Also, the new file will be owned by the user that edited it, even if the original file was owned by someone else.

When TextEdit says the file is "locked", that really just means it's not going to be able to edit it. The file could have its "locked" flag (aka uchg) set, or you might not have write access to it (not strictly required, but TextEdit is "polite" and will refuse to edit no-write files), or not have write access to its directory, or whatever.

BTW, what do you mean about UF_NOUNLINK "actively being thwarted by macOS"
Filesystems vary in what attributes they support, and neither HFS+ nor APFS support that flag. Not all do.

Comment: Thank you. That was what I feared—the unlinking during edit/save. As for UF_NOUNLINK, I'm referring to **[this article](https://rixstep.com/2/2/20200311,00.shtml)**: you can actually write that flag, but not with the `chflags` command. Tested it myself with Rixstep's Xattrib. However, the flag is immediately deleted by NSDocumentController when opening a saving a file with this flag, and no matter what, you can still remove (unlink) it, because the file system doesn't care about that flag either. Interesting nonetheless.

Comment: But back to the original topic: So all of this would basically mean that there is no way on macOS to prevent accidental deletion of files, while retaining all other rights like write/edit, unless it's a file you only plan on dealing with in shell scripts. I know that `uchg` works to some extent with some applications; e.g. Rixstep's Rixedit unlocks the file (like TextEdit) for editing, then (unlike TextEdit) re-locks it after saving. But I don't think a lot of applications do that, i.e. scan for `uchg`, and then put the flag back after the job is done.